# xamarin ios Ipad device the accents are replaced by question mark

Tags: c#, ipad, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have developed xamarin ios app and deployed on Iphone and IPad devices. on Iphone the Tigrinya language characters are displaying correctly but on Ipad the characters are replaced by question mark? I wonder if the issue is on Ipad device configuration or on the application code? Images below are showing on Ipad and Iphone devices respectively

[image: On Ipad Device]

[image: On mobile device]

Comment: Is the iOS version of iPad the same as the iPhone you test?

Comment: They are different. IOS version for IPad is 10.3 and for Iphone IOS version is 12.14

Comment: I'm not sure if it is caused by version and showing a question mark box probably means the system does not support that language yet.